# How I create a loop for adding words into string python

Tags: python

I was trying to learn python through creating script whenever it is necessary, even just for a simple math calculation for instance. So I want to create a automatic twitter paragraph separate-r, and perhaps read a .txt file and auto-twit, those are afterwords.

I had my logic use a loop. First, to count whether if the sentence needed to be separated into multiple ones. If so, it would be over 280 characters (twitter limit) it would use split to break it up, and then run the loop of appending 280 characters into a new string into a list.

Here is what I have got so far...sorry

```
longtext = input()

while True:

  if len(longtext) <= 280:
    print(len(longtext))
    break

  else:
    splited = longtext.split()
    new280 = []

    for i in range(len(splited)):

      if i % 280 == 0:
        new280.append()
        new280twiforcopy = ''.join(new280)
```

I know this is probably not good at all, but I am very much stucked...

For example:

input:

```
some kind of 400 words text string...
"xxx  * 400"
```

output:

```
"xxx *280"
"xxx *120"
```

(x means characters)

Comment: could you comment a bit your code? I don't understand the goal to the first test and I don't see in your code the 280 limits. Your question will be way easier to answer if you could provide a minimal example (small input and the expected output)

Comment: What is `while True:` for? `firstlist` is changed by only outside of the loop.

Comment: @RomainL. Sorry! my bad, i was testing 10 words instead of 280 for the draft...I have edited the input and expected output now.

Comment: @BoseongChoi I thought I should keep appending split words up to 280 in the loop?

Comment: Then you should update `longtext` itself. or it goes infinite loop.

Comment: After letting time to people answer your question ( like 244-48h) When you have an answer that give you satisfaction you should mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark left of it.

Answer (score 1):

The following might help:

```py
# consider my firstlist is made up of x*400
firstlist = 'x' * 400

if len(firstlist) <= 280:
  print(len(firstlist))
else:
  new280 = []
  while len(firstlist) > 280:
    new280.append(firstlist[:280])
    firstlist = firstlist[280:]
  new280.append(firstlist)

for i in new280:
  print(i)
```

**Output:**

xxx.... (*280 times*)

xxx.... (*120 times*)

---

You can test the code [here](https://repl.it/repls/PreemptiveFilthyLicense).

Comment: OMG, this is amazing!

Comment: @NelsonWang Happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

In python you can slice and index list

```
tot_length = len(longtext)

i = 0
increment = 280

while i < tot_length:
    print([longtext[i: i + increment]])
    i += increment
```

Comment: Thank you! this one works even better, because it literally give out two strings! thanks